# Expandablelistview Click on child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How can I implement click on child to show layout ?

I based on [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/):

It should be like this:

```
      @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
    if(View.equals.("Core")
        {
          //code
        }      
        }
    });
```

Comment: could you elaborate the question?

Comment: What do you mean to show layout - to show the layout of the child or clicking on the child to show another layout that is not directly embedded in the Adapter (e.g. getChildView/getGroupView) ?

Comment: I based on example: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/

and on click Core I would like open view, Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an OnChildClickListener to the ExpandableListView.

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick (ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id){
    // your code here
}
```

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html

Comment: Can you do example for "Core".
http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/expandablelistview/android-expandablelistview-example/